# Multiple regex inside controller instead of mutliple routes with single regex

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I run Laravel 5.4.

I have those routes :

```
<?php
    Route::get('/users/{name}', 'UsersController@showByText')->where('name', '[\w]+');
    Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UsersController@showById')->where('id', '[\d]+');
?>
```

And my controllers :

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class DashboardController extends Controller
    {

        function showByText($name)
        {
            return DB::table('users')->where('name', 'LIKE', $name)->get();
        }

        function showById($id)
        {
            return DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
        }
    }
?>
```

Question :

Could I end up with one single method, to be able to do :

```
<?php
    Route::get('/users/{mixed}', 'UsersController@show');
?>
```

And my controller would look like :

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class DashboardController extends Controller
    {
        function show()
        {
            if( Request::match('mixed', '[\w]+') )
            {
                return DB::table('users')->where('name', 'LIKE', $mixed)->get();
            }
            else if( Request::match('mixed', '[\d]+') )
            {
                return DB::table('users')->where('id', $mixed)->get();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I know `Request::match()` does not exists, and knowing that `Route::pattern('id', '[\d]+');` will force my method `show` to be compliant only for digits. I would like to know if there is a shorthand for `preg_match()` with the `Request` component.

Comment: what about `if( is_numeric($mixed) )` and you pass `$mixed` to your function defintion as a parameter.

Comment: I would prefer a Request or a Laravel helper but let's to this mate, hope some Laravel Evangelist come to this topic and hear my voice :)